# Rest controller is not detected during spring boot auto componing scan

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I had a problem where my rest controller was not handling requests and after debugging it appears that it was not detected by the container and I had to add`@ComponentScan`(`./restController`) on the main function. I don't understand why this happens as spring boot should be `autoscanning` all the components on startup.

This is my rest controller.

```
@RestController
public class RegistryController {
@GetMapping(path= "registration/hey")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login( ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("hello");
}
    }
```

And by adding `@ComponentScan("restController")`it worked :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("restController")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the package structure, where are `DemoApplication` and `RegistryController` located?  By default, spring-boot scans everything in and "beneath" the package of the `@SpringBootApplication`. If we have beans in a package that is not in or "beneath" the `@SpringBootApplication`, we have to configure the root package(s) through `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: DemoApplication is under src/com.example.demo and RegistryController is under src/restController

Comment: Well there you have your answer.

Comment: so the correct package structure would be src/com.example.demo/restController ?

Comment: The correct package structure is whatever you decide is the correct package structure. This is why spring-boot provides the possibility to configure the root(s) for component scanning.